# Constructor RemoteWebDriver(URL, ChromeOptions) is undefined

Tags: java, constructor, undefined, remotewebdriver

In creating my ChromeGridTest.java package, Eclipse is throwing the following error...

'The constructor RemoteWebDriver(URL, ChromeOptions) is undefined'
'hubURL cannot be resolved to a variable'
'URL cannot be resolved to a type'

Q: How do I fix this so that I can check that my hub and node are running?

```
public class ChromeGridTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //1.define Desired Capabilities:
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setBrowserName("chrome");
    cap.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);

    //2.Chrome Options definition:
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.merge(cap);

    String hubUrl = "http://192.168.31.1:4444/wd/hub";
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL),options);

    driver.get("http://www.freecrm.com");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    }

}
```

I expect for Chrome to be launched, and for freecrm.com to be landed on -- all as a test of my Grid's proper setup.

Comment: @thepooran thank you for the edit.

Comment: You are using the variable name hubURL in your URL constructor, not hubUrl.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @JoshSullivan.  With this correction, I am now getting a 'URL cannot be resolved to a type' error.

Comment: Solution: I just imported java.net.URL and my code was accepted; thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Solution: After editing `hubURL` to `hubUrl`, and then including `import java.net.URL;` no errors thrown.